# How to pass parameters to jQuery function when using Laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I'm trying to pass the value of a star rating using [rateYo](https://github.com/prrashi/rateYo) and the log gives me a:

> 4main.js:11 undefined

the way its set up, it uses the div to get a value. I'm trying to set the value for the star, and ultimately pass the value to route params. The backend PHP works, it's just a matter of passing the parameters.

**Show.blade.php**

```
<h5>Click to rate:</h5>

<form action="{{ route('rate', $book->id) }}" method="POST">
   {!! csrf_field() !!}
    <!-- <input id="rateYo" name="val" value="0" type="text"> -->
      <div id="rateYo" name="val"></div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">submit</button>
</form>
```

**Main.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  'use strict'
  $('#rateYo').rateYo({
    starWidth: "40px"
  });

  $('#rateYo').click(function() {
    var owl = $('#rateYo').val();
    console.log(owl);

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'rate/' + owl,
      success: function(data) {
        // $("#msg").html(data.msg);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

**Route**

```
Route::post('rate/{book_id}','BookController@rate')->name('rate');
```

Comment: did you try `var owl = $('#rateYo').text();` ?

Comment: let me try this out

Comment: still undefined

Comment: do you have value in `rateYo` div ?

Comment: well the value is a star

`<div id="rateYo" name="val"></div>`, its just the way the plugin is set up.

Comment: I do not see any `val()` method defined in the docs. Have you tried this `var owl = $('#rateYo').rateYo('rating');`? It seems like thats te way? http://rateyo.fundoocode.ninja/#method-rating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See plugin documentation from http://rateyo.fundoocode.ninja/.
You can not get rating value using val() function.

Try using

```
var rating = $rateYo.rateYo("rating");
console.log(rating)
```